# finding text using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to find an element and hide it using jQuery.

Can anybody see why this would not work?

HTML:

```
 <span class='a'>2</span>
```

jQuery:

```
 var abc = '2';

 $(".a:contains(abc)").hide();
```

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
$(".a:contains(" + abc + ")").hide();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) too!

```
var abc = '2';

$('.a').filter(function() {
   return ( $(this).text() === abc ); //use this if you want exact match with the content
})
.hide();

$('.a').filter(function() {
   return ( $(this).text().indexOf(abc) != -1 ); //use this if you want contains match with the content.
})
.hide();
```

Comment: Great!!! Downvoter, do you mind if I ask why? In programming you will always find more than one way to do the same thing. I am just adding another variation.

Comment: No clue why this was downvoted!Upvoting it.

Comment: This is basically what the `:contains()` selector does internally since it's a jQuery selector (not a CSS selector), so this is just more explicit (which I like). Two things I just realized - you could combine it into one line (one `return` statement) but shouldn't affect anything. And the other thing is that this doesn't mimic **contains** - this requires the `.text()` value be **equal to** `abc`, which doesn't seem right. What you need is something like `return $(this).text().indexOf(abc) > -1;`. Also, the OP asks why their code doesn't work, not for an alternative (although I like this)

Comment: @Ian : I am not trying to behave like an expert but could you tell us what isn't right with using `.text()`

Comment: @harsha (I didn't downvote, by the way, I was just trying to explain why this answer technically isn't right). Using `.text()` is fine, but the selector the OP uses is `:contains()`, which basically says "if the element's text **contains** the following text"...not "**equals** the following text". This answer tries to match the text exactly, but it needs to see if the text **contains**

Comment: @Ian I didn't say that you downvoted it.I asked what's wrong with `.text()` is because I need to understand what's wrong with it.

Comment: @Ian: 2 `return` statements are just for the sake of readability. I don't even use the second one personally. And, yes, i do thought about `indexOf` over `===`, but just look at OP, I am really not getting what he wants, either he wants the `exact` match or `contains`.

Comment: @harsha I just wanted you guys to know I didn't downvote, that's all. There's nothing wrong with `.text()` - the "problem" is that `===` doesn't imitate what `:contains()` does

Comment: @TamilVendhan Absolutely, I was just pointing out the possibility of condensing into one statement. The problem is solved by the other answer. I guess with the OP's simple example, you can't be sure if they want to match exactly or see if it contains, but the fact that they use `:contains()` makes me think the latter. I guess a little explanation and example of each could be useful. I think if they want an exact match, your answer is 100% needed, otherwise your approach would just be alternative (a good one)

Comment: @Ian: ya, i got lazy. Updating it. Thanks man!

Comment: @TamilVendhan No problem, just trying to help you out and get a more complete answer for the OP. I think it was a great idea in the first place, just needs a little explanation to help them understand :)

Comment: @Ian: I like it & will keep this in mind when answering. Thanks again. Updated the answer.